# How can you turn a string that contains an equation into a readable and solvable equation in Lua

Tags: string, lua, integer, equation

I am currently attempting to write a calculator (as a learning project) but am having troubles turning an equation in a string to a solveable equation that can be read. This is my code so far:

```
io.write('Please insert equation: ', '\n' )


--Variables
local equation = io.read()
local restart = 1
local incorrect = 0
local numberthingy = tostring(tonumber(equation))


while restart == 1 do
    io.write('Is this correct? (Y/N): ', equation, '\n')
    local choice = io.read()
    if choice == 'Y' then
        print(numberthingy)
        restart = 0
    elseif choice == 'N' then
        incorrect = 1
        while incorrect == 1 do --restarts entire while loop if incorrect
            io.write('Please insert equation: ', '\n')
            equation = io.read()
            restart = 1
            break
        end
    else
        print("Please Choose Applicable Options")
        restart = 1
    end
end
```

I'm expecting an answer such as 3 when entering 1 + 2 or any other equation but I am continuously recieving `nil`

Comment: `tonumber` converts a string to a number - no more, no less. It *does not* parse or evaluate arithmetic expressions like `1 + 2`. Thus you're getting `nil` when passing it an arithmetic expression, because that is not in number format and thus invalid. You *could* load & execute your arithmetic expressions as Lua using `load` and prepending a `return `.

Comment: `numberthingy = ((loadstring or load)("return "..equation) or function() return 'ERROR' end)()`